# Как перевести URL (slug) в Wordpress с русского на английский?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, slug

В WordPress по умолчанию генерируется `URL` (в WP это называется `slug`) на основе заголовка поста. К примеру, Из заголовка `"Привет мой мир"` мы получим адрес `"привет-мой-мир"`.

Возможно ли автоматически создавать ссылки постов в Wordpress на английском языке? Чтобы из `"Привет мой мир"` в адресе был `"hello-my-world"`?

Вариант с транслитерацией не подходит – нужен именно перевод. Есть ли какой-то плагин для этого?

Comment: Что понимается под "перевести"? Перевод самого термина - оффтопик для этого коммьюнити. Перевод интерфейса конкретного плагина - тоже оффтопик, списывайтесь с автором плагина.

Comment: @A K это веб-термин. И никакие плагины не причём: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL#Slug

Comment: Всегда пользуюсь плагином [Cyr-to-Lat](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cyr2lat/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вариант с транслитерацией не подходит, нужен именно перевод.

Ну если так - использовать API сервисов-переводчиков в своём плагине.

Answer (score 0):

Для этой цели я разработал плагин [**MobiDevices Translate URL**](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/mobidevices-translate-url/), который работает на основе Яндекс Переводчика, что обеспечивает отличное качество перевода.

Плагин удаляет из полученных URL английские предлоги и артикли, которые не влияют на продвижение, однако увеличивает длину ссылок.

**MobiDevices Translate URL** правильно форматирует переведенный URL и очень легкий в установке и работе.